# Problem with Gravity Forms - multistep form

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I have a multistep form in my website built using Gravity Forms plugin, in the first page there's a phone number input, and when the user goes to the next step an OTP is sent to the phone number. All goes well when there is no validation error in the first page. But when there is some validation error on the first page and user corrects the error and goes to the next step, the OTP API returns an error saying Browser sent an invalid request.

Comment: Welcome to WPSE! Plugin support is considered off-topic, especially for paid plugins. If you contact the Gravity Forms support team they will be better able to assist.

Comment: Hi Infozzle, welcome to [wordpress.se]. As a rule, the community considers questions about third-party plugins such as Gravity Forms off-topic so you might notice some down-votes and answers might be somewhat scarce. You can find out what questions are a good fit [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).